# Copy many large files from the host to a docker container and back

Tags: docker

I am a beginner with Docker and I have been searching for 2 days now and I do not understand which would be a better solution.

I have a docker container on a Ubuntu server. I need to copy many large video files to the Ubuntu host via FTP. Docker via cron will process the videos using ffmpeg and save the result to the Ubuntu host somehow so the files are accessible via FTP.

What is the best solution:

- create a bind drive - I understand the host may change files in the bind drive
- create a volume but I do not understand how may I add files to the volume
- create a folder on the Ubuntu and have a cron that will copy using "docker cp" command and after a video has been processed to copy it to the host?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind-mounting a host directory for this is probably the best approach, for exactly the reasons you lay out: both the host and container can directly read and write to it, but the host can't easily write to a named volume.  `docker cp` is tricky, you note the problem of knowing when the process is completed, and anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can pretty trivially root the host; you don't want to give this permission to something network-facing.

If you're designing a larger-scale system, you also might consider an approach where no files are actually shared at all.  The upload server sends the files (maybe via HTTP POST) to an internal storage service, then posts a message to a message queue (maybe RabbitMQ).  That then retrieves the files from the storage service, does its work, uploads the result, and posts a response message.  The big advantages of this approach are being able to run it on multiple systems, easily being able to scale the individual components of it, and not needing to worry about filesystem permissions.  But, it's a much more involved design.